# SQLParameter incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sqlparameter

I have 2 spots where I need to use `SQLParameter` to parse SQL. One works and one does not and I cannot figure out why the second one doesn't work.

The first one that works is the following:

```
   SqlCommand getShopDbNameCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 [mappeddbName] FROM [ECM].[dbo].[EcmShop]" +
        "WHERE [LicencePassCode] = @licCode AND [iPadLocation] = @shopId", this.mainConnection);
    getShopDbNameCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("licCode", currUser.LicCode));
    getShopDbNameCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("shopId", currUser.ShopID));
```

That works. On top of that, the majority of the tutorials I've read all say that I do not have to have a `@` in front of the parameter name inside of the `new SqlParameter`, only inside of the command text itself do I need a `@` in front of the parameter name.

The second command I am trying to run is the following:

```
  string getAuthCommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + shopDbName + "].[dbo].[MessageLink]" +
  "WHERE [objectname] LIKE %" + "@compareStringA"+ "% OR [objectname] LIKE %" + "@compareStringB" +"%";
  SqlCommand getAuthCommand = new SqlCommand(getAuthCommandText, this.mainConnection);
  getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("compareStringA", "ABRAUTH"));
  getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("compareStringB", "ABRSAUTH"));
```

This does not work and throws an invalid syntax error. Using breakpoints it still looks like the command is trying to pass the literal `@compareString` string to SQL and thats whats causing the issue. Ive seen other posts on SOF that say to use the literal parameter name when defining `new SqlParameter` objects (meaning include the `@`) but everywhere outside of SoF say otherwise.

Any reason why the second command would throw invalid syntax errors?

Comment: I see you do `this.mainConnection`, are you only opening one connection and reusing the connection throughout your code? `SqlConnection` was not designed to be used this way, it uses [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) and what should be done is just open and dispose many short lived connections. When you dispose a connection it leaves the connection open to the database for a little while, if it sees a new connection open using the same connection string it will re-use the old connection.

Comment: I see you do `this.mainConnection`, are you only opening one connection and reusing the connection throughout your code? `SqlConnection` was not designed to be used this way, it uses [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) and what should be done is just open and dispose many short lived connections. When you dispose a connection it leaves the connection open to the database for a little while, if it sees a new connection open using the same connection string it will re-use the old connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your LIKE statements must be inside single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%s%';
```

Comment: While true they also need to add the `%` to the value that they pass to the parameter for this to work.  That or concatenate them in the query.

Answer (score 2):

> the majority of the tutorials I've read all say that I do not have to have a @ in front of the parameter name inside of the new SqlParameter,

The C# code for `SqlParameter` does not care if you put a `@` in the front or not when adding it to the `Parameters` collection, it will put a `@` behind the scenes for you.

For your query that is not working the correct way to do it is you will actually have 3 strings you add together in sql, the two `'%'` and your parameter. I am also changing the way you add parameters to explicitly set the data type, it is better to do that with strings.

```
  string getAuthCommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + shopDbName + "].[dbo].[MessageLink]" +
  "WHERE [objectname] LIKE ('%' + @compareStringA + '%') OR [objectname] LIKE ('%' + @compareStringB +'%')";
  SqlCommand getAuthCommand = new SqlCommand(getAuthCommandText, this.mainConnection);
  getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add("@compareStringA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "ABRAUTH"; //I had to guess on your datatype, I just did varchar(20), change as appropriate.
  getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add("@compareStringB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "ABRSAUTH";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 string getAuthCommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + shopDbName + "].[dbo].[MessageLink] " +
 "WHERE [objectname] LIKE " + "@compareStringA"+ " OR [objectname] LIKE " + "@compareStringB" +"";
 SqlCommand getAuthCommand = new SqlCommand(getAuthCommandText, this.mainConnection);
 getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("compareStringA", "%ABRAUTH%"));
 getAuthCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("compareStringB", "%ABRSAUTH%"));
```